# Render Animation Just renders cloth animation

Tags: rendering, animation, armature, cloth-simulation

I'm currently working on a animation of a 3D model to then output as a 2D pixel. I have everything ready to go: mesh, bones, weights, action, etc.
When I play it on the viewport, beautiful! Everything works just as I want it to. If I also render individual frames (F12), also works beautifully. However, when I do a "render animation", things get really weird; The body/bones freeze on the current frame and just the clothes are rendered.
I have exhausted all my search options and I'm stuck on this for a few days now. Does anyone have any clue of what it might be? Output settings are set with the correct frames start, end and step, Eevee is set to the default. Also I have tried to create a new file and import the objects into this one, and the same thing happens :(

I'm using Blender 2.83.2.

[image]

A video of whats happening: https://youtu.be/rHJZtGqspco
Some screen shots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/orraK.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there do not entirely depend on your .blend file to get answers .Please use image of your viewport, render etc.Thank U

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 I've added a video of what's happening and some screenshots. Tell me whatever else you need and I'll provide it :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for uploading the files i took a look at your .blend file and I found out that your cloth animation freezes around the 9th frame. To solve this you have to play the entire animation in the viewport that is always necessary while doing cloth simulations .play it until the end and then bake the simulation

Comment: The animation render perfectly for me with cycles .Also do the same for hair and the hat lace the bones aren't freezing when I rendered it(with cycles). Can't use eevee since my potato pc is not supporting it. Check this out- https://imgur.com/a/LjIsNxt

Comment: Thanks for the update! Could you share you cycles render config, please?

Comment: I haven't changed anything in the cycles render properties . Even it has the same resolution you have kept the only undesired thing in the render was lighting. It wasn't the as in eevee .In cycles it kinda looks flat.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I ended up ditching all the animations on that files and started from scratched, figured it might have some cache or something messing up with things. Now things are looking good again. I'm just saving a backup each day so I can prevent this from happening again.